# Google Apps Script: How to specify to only pull back files with certain file names

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a folder 35000 images in and growing. I need to extract the file name and the URL of the file.
I had been using this but its now timing out, so I want to pop in that it looks for a file name begining with x but I havent the foggiest how to! Please help!

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'Salesforce Images';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }
```

I've tried a few of the rabit holes that Google search threw up but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function listFolderContents(name) {
  var foldername = 'Salesforce Images';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFilesByName(name);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
}
```

Comment: Saddly I can't get this to bring anything back, the file names are "78-01-011 - Front" or "78-01-011 - Mount" So I tried putting 'contains "78-"' in the (name) part of the  var contents = folder.getFilesByName(name); I tried putting just '78-', '78-01-011 - Front' nothing. Sorry I've never worked with this before so I am sure its blisteringly obvious and its me being dense.

Comment: Yeah well I personally need more explanation perhaps some tables with your data

Comment: If you provided us with adequate information you would already have an answer.

Comment: So I have a folder with 36291 (and growing) .png files. The file format is a product SKU (00-00-000 OR 00-000000) - FRONT or Mount. Examples 03-03-024 - Front 03-03-024 - Mount, 40-001096 - Front, 40-001096 - Mount. I am after an sheet ith one column displaying the file name (This is so I can match it to our CRM), then one with the URL (this is so I can get the file's ID so I can format a URL to push into our CRM). Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of that information  should be posted in your question.

Comment: I appologise, this is my first foray into this.

Comment: Perhaps you should spend some time at the [help]